# Error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException con Date.valueOf

Tags: java

Estoy generando este boton:

```
private void btModificarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if (this.validarDatos()) {
            Paciente pac = new Paciente();
            pac.setnum_asegurado(Integer.parseInt(txtnum_asegurado.getText()));
            pac.setNombre(txtNombre.getText());
            pac.setDireccion(txtDireccion.getText());
            pac.setEdad(Integer.parseInt(txtEdad.getText()));
            pac.setfecha_nacimiento(Date.valueOf(txtfecha_nacimiento.getText()));
            pac.sete_mail(txte_mail.getText());
            pac.setTelefono(Integer.parseInt(txtTelefono.getText()));
            pac.setProfesion(txtProfesion.getText());
            int res = this.pacBo.modificar(pac);
            switch (res) {
                case 0: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Paciente Modificado Correctamente.");
                  break;
                case 1: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se pudo conectar a la BD.");
                  break;
                case 2: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Problemas Almancenando Datos.");
                  break;  
                case 3: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Modificando Datos en la BD.");
                  break;  
            }
            llenarTabla();
            limpiar();
        }
```

Pero me genera este error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:143)
    at ventanas.MantPaciente.btModificarActionPerformed(MantPaciente.java:385)
    at ventanas.MantPaciente.access$200(MantPaciente.java:20)
    at ventanas.MantPaciente$4.actionPerformed(MantPaciente.java:182)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
```

Alguno podria aclararme por que. 
muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

La documentación para [Date.valueOf(string)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) especifica que si no le pasas una fecha en el formato `yyyy-[m]m-[d]d`, entonces te tira un `IllegalArgumentException`.

Evidentemente, `txtfecha_nacimiento.getText()` no contiene una cadena en ese formato.

De modo que para arreglar tu problema, puedes 1) asegurarte de que `txtfecha_nacimiento.getText()` esté en el formato `yyyy-[m]m-[d]d`, o 2) puedes usar `SimpleDateFormat` para convertir la fecha especificando el formato que tu quieres.

Por ejemplo, si la cadena está en el formato `dd/mm/yyyy`, entonces puedes hacer la conversión de la siguiente manera:

```
pac.setfecha_nacimiento(
    new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
        .parse(txtfecha_nacimiento.getText()));
```

Comment: Lo modifique asi:pac.setfecha_nacimiento((Date) new SimpleDateFormat ("YYYY/MM/dd").parse(txtfecha_nacimiento.getText()));java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "19831201"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366) me dio este error!" entiendo que es el formato, pero no logro ajustarme a cual es el que debo usar

Comment: No es difícil determinar el formato.  Si tu cadena es `19831201`, entonces el formato es `yyyyMMdd`: `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")`. Pero una vez que escojas el formato adecuado, no puedes estar entrando fechas en el textbox con todo tipo de formato. Debes mantenerte a un formato de forma consistente.

Answer (score 1):

Corrige esta linea:  (Date.valueOf(txtfecha_nacimiento.getText()) , usa SimpleDateFormat

Comment: cambie la sentencia por esta:
            
            
            SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
            String fecha_nac = formato.format(pac.getfecha_nacimiento());           Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1770)
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:943)
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:936)